# Is it possible to create a shockwave gun (Like in Minority Report)

Tags: forces, pressure, explosions, shock-waves

I love the gun in Minority Report. It seems to send a shockwave that can throw people and objects back. The gun has a rotating mechanism that triggers the action and loads a charge.

Here's it in action: http://gph.is/29xazEx

I Googled shockwave guns but it was mostly pressurized air inside of plastics tubes. Very uncool and mostly fit to destroy flowers or topple pencils.

For it to be usable as a sidearm it would have to be:

- Light
- Portable
- Produce sufficient force WITHOUT actually exploding
- NOT throw the user back or break his arm

**Now would it be possible to create this gun in real life - assuming you had an army of researchers?**

If not, what are the physical impossibilities?

Thanks for indulging me.

Comment: This question is about engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device doesn't have to generate shock waves.  A vortex ring generator will do.  When I was in grad school (1960s) I attended a lecture where a demonstration was presented that was basically any empty coffee can with the top and bottom removed and a rubber membrane secured over one end with a strong rubber band.  A clamp around the can served as a handle to hold it in place.  The lecturer lite a cigarette and blew smoke into the can and then hit the rubber membrane with a rubber hammer while holding the can stationary with his other hand.  This sent a 15 cm diameter smoke ring propagating across the lecture hall.  He then had a person wear a hat while standing at the far end of the lecture hall and showed that a properly aimed vortex ring could knock the hat off (estimated distance of 10 m).

This isn't the kind of "gun" shown in your linked video, but it does give an indication of what could be done with a simple vortex ring generator.  Of course (as with all guns) recoil would have to be taken into account which would probably compromise some of your requirements.

Comment: WOW! So it's not just science fiction? This is awesome, thanks for pointing me to the right place. I have some YouTubing to do I see.

Thanks a bunch for your answer. I greatly appreciate it.